# Raw SQL for sharing a crm document

Tags: dynamics-crm

In MSCRM I'd like to automate sharing documents out to users.  I tried using SQL Server Profiler to trace but I can't find the raw sql.  Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Going directly to SQL in MSCRM is rarely a good idea. Why don't you use the API ?

Comment: You mean the SDK?  I'll take a look.

Comment: What do you mean by "sharing documents out to users" ? What kind of documents ?

Comment: by "sharing" I mean the CRM function of "sharing".  Not SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

How you do this depends largely on where you're storing the documents (on a file server, within CRM, on SharePoint etc) and also how you want to "share" the document (email a link to a file server location, email an attached document, provide access to doc via CRM UI).

If Sharepoint is part of the equation there's various add-ons / webparts available that integrate document management with CRM. If your document is within CRM you could look at creating a workflow that either emailed a link, or provided access rights within CRM or something similar. You approach would also depend on if you're sharing with CRM users, CRM contacts, or some other type of user.

If you've built a custom form or application then you should be using the API as driis mentions. Whatever the scenario there shouldn't be a need to find the "raw" sql to achieve this.

Comment: by "sharing" I mean the CRM function of "sharing".  Not SharePoint.  I've created custom entity and the records associated with this entity will be shared out.  I should've pointed out this is CRM v.4.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the definitions of "Filtered***" view there is a bit of sql like

**select  POA.ObjectId from PrincipalObjectAccess POA 
        join SystemUserPrincipals sup on POA.PrincipalId = sup.PrincipalId
            where sup.SystemUserId = u.SystemUserId and
                POA.ObjectTypeCode = 10039 AND 
                ((POA.AccessRightsMask | POA.InheritedAccessRightsMask) & 1)=1**

Adding new rows to PrincipalObjectAccess  should do the trick. However, it's a hack, it requires administrative privileges and is highly unrecommended on general principles...